# Read a string with apostrophe from a JTextField and save it on a database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jtextfield

I have many `JTextField` objects and I want to read, in one of them, a string that contains apostrophes and then, this It will be saved on a database. The problem is when I try to save this string, because I obtain this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error 
    in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
    server version for the right syntax to use near 'k')' at line 1
```

I put the apostrophe in a `JTextField` and the "k" letter is in the next `JTextField`. I can't understand if who can't read this kind of character is the database (I have a database written in SQL and I use MySQL), or the `JTextField` object. What can I do?

This is the code that save the strings caught from the `JTextField` objects (I  get the strings into another method, simply using the method `jTextField.getText();`):

```
public void setNuovaAzienda(){
    try {
        int contCliente = 0;
        Class.forName(NOMEDRIVER); //avvio il driver
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(SERVERURL, USER, PASSWORD);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        Statement st1 = conn.createStatement();
        Statement st2 = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(IdCliente) FROM cliente");

        while (rs.next())
            contCliente = rs.getInt(1);

        contCliente++;
        int showConfirmDialog = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Vuoi confermare l'inserimento del nuovo cliente?", "Conferma Inserimento", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (showConfirmDialog == 0) {
            try {
                st1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO cliente () VALUES ('"+contCliente+"', '"+citta+"', '"+indirizzo+"', '"+nCivico+"', '"+telefono+"')");
                st2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO personagiuridica () VALUES ('"+contCliente+"', '"+partitaIva+"', '"+nomeAzienda+"', '"+ragSociale+"', '"+fax+"')");
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\salva\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication10\\src\\javaapplication7\\Icons\\icona v.png");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente Inserito", "Conferma Inserimento", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
                InserisciOrdine linkInserisciOrdine;
                linkInserisciOrdine = new InserisciOrdine();
                linkInserisciOrdine.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                linkInserisciOrdine.setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NuovaAzienda.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NuovaAzienda.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

contCliente, citta, indirizzo, etc. are global variable.

Comment: what's the sql that's giving you error? Any code?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you construct your SQL statements as a String, embedding the data directly, like

```
String dataString = ...; //get value from field
String sql = "INSERT INTO `mytable` (`col`) VALUES ('"+dataString+"')";
```

This is wrong, since if you have single quote in your string, this will result in invalid statement. Try outputting that string to `System.out` and executing it in the SQL worksheet, you should see what goes wrong. You should use [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead:

```
//Assuming you have jdbc Connection named conn
String dataString = ...; //get value from field
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `mytable` (`col`) VALUES (?)");
ps.setString(1, dataString);
ps.execute();
ps.close();
```

It will give you a decent protection against SQL injections as a bonus.

If you are unable to rewrite your code with prepared statements (e.g. legacy third-party API), then you should *escape* single quotes in your string, by replacing them with two single quotes (`'` -> `''`).

**UPDATE**

Indeed you do construct the statements using concatenation. AVOID THIS, unless you want to get hacked by a random script kiddie one day. Read about SQL injections, there's plenty of info, and they are one of the main vectors of hacker attacks.

Comment: Now I try it. Sorry, but I can't understand what do you mean with "Indeed you do construct the statements using concatenation."

Comment: I posted my answer just before you posted your code snippet, so I had to guess, and later edited it because I guessed right. I'm not a native speaker, so certain sentences might sound wrong =)